# Index based style.format

Tags: python, pandas

You can specify a format for each column by using `df.style.format()`, however, i want this behavior but then index based instead of column based. I realise its a bit more tricky because a column has a specific datatype, and a row can be mixed.

Is there a workaround to get it anyway? The `df.style.apply()` method has the flexibility, but i don't think it supports number formatting, only (CSS) styling.

Some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[150.00, 181.00, 186.00],
                   [  5.85,   3.73,   2.12]], 
                  index=['Foo', 'Bar'],
                  columns=list('ABC'))
```

[image]

If i transpose the Dataframe, is easy:

```
mapper = {'Foo': '{:.0f}',
          'Bar': '{:.1f}%'}   

df.T.style.format(mapper)
```

[image]

But i want this formatting without transposing, something like:

`df.style.format(mapper, axis=1)`

Comment: Do you really have to use the `Styler` class for this? I think `df.apply(lambda s: s.map(mapper.get(s.name).format), axis=1)` should go a long way.

Comment: I don't, but somehow i thought i needed the `Styler` for this. I will accept this if you post it as an answer, it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need to use the `Styler` class for this if the target is to re-format row values. You can use that `mapper` dictionary to match the formats you want, through a `map` and `apply` combination by row. The following should be a decent start:

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.map(mapper.get(s.name).format), axis=1)
```

Thanks!